# Test a function that contains assert statement and doesn't return anything

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

If, for example, I have a function like this:

```
def func(inputs: List):
    """ function to test
        args: inputs (list of tuples)
    """
    for elem in inputs:
        assert elem[0].attr1 == elem[1].attr1 
        assert elem[0].attr2 == elem[1].attr2 
        if hasttr(elem[0], "attr3") & hasttr(elem[1], "attr3"):
            assert elem[0].attr3 == elem[1].attr3
```

How can I write the test for this function using `pytest`?
I know we can use this code (source: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/assert.html):

```
import pytest

def myfunc():
    raise ValueError("Exception 123 raised")

def test_match():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError, match=r".* 123 .*"):
        myfunc()
```

to test a function that raise a `ValueError`, but what about `assert`?
Thank you!

Comment: `assert` will raise an [`AssertionError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#AssertionError) if it asserts something false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per one of the comments, you can simply check for [`AssertionError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#AssertionError):

```python
import pytest

def myfunc():
   # some code
   assert 0 == 1, "boom"  # raises AssertionError

def test_myfunc():
    with pytest.raises(AssertionError, match=r".*boom.*"):
        myfunc()
```

If an `AssertionError` hasn't been raised by `myfunc()`, `test_myfunc()` will fail with:

```
Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'AssertionError'>
```

If an `AssertionError` with a *different* message has been raised by `myfunc()`, the test will fail with:

```
AssertionError: Regex pattern ... does not match ...
```